# Difference between Date class in Package java.util & Package java.sql

Tags: java, date

In java, both the `java.util` and the `java.sql` package contain a `Date` class, So what is the difference between them?

If one `Date` class is present in Java then what is the need of another `Date` class?

Answer (score 16):

From [the JavaDoc of `java.sql.Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html):

> A thin wrapper around a millisecond value that allows JDBC to identify this as an SQL DATE value. A milliseconds value represents the number of milliseconds that have passed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT.
>
> To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values wrapped by a `java.sql.Date` instance must be 'normalized' by setting the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the particular time zone with which the instance is associated.

**Explanation:** A `java.util.Date` represents date and time of day, a `java.sql.Date` only represents a date (the complement of java.sql.Date is [`java.sql.Time`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html), which only represents a time of day, but also extends `java.util.Date`).

Answer (score 4):

These answers seem to be partially outdated.

I just read a little API Code (Java Version 1.8.0_91) and found this in `java.sql.Date`:

```
/**
 * Creates a date which corresponds to the day determined by the supplied
 * milliseconds time value {@code theDate}.
 *
 * @param theDate
 *            a time value in milliseconds since the epoch - January 1 1970
 *            00:00:00 GMT. The time value (hours, minutes, seconds,
 *            milliseconds) stored in the {@code Date} object is adjusted to
 *            correspond to 00:00:00 GMT on the day determined by the supplied
 *            time value.
 */
public Date(long theDate) {
    super(normalizeTime(theDate));
}

/*
 * Private method which normalizes a Time value, removing all low
 * significance digits corresponding to milliseconds, seconds, minutes and
 * hours, so that the returned Time value corresponds to 00:00:00 GMT on a
 * particular day.
 */
private static long normalizeTime(long theTime) {
    return theTime;
}
```

The method for normalizing the time is still there and even the comment says that the time will be normalized to 00:00:00 GMT but it does nothing. For some reason they removed the normalization, wich means, that a `java.sql.Date` contains just like a `java.util.Date` just the number of milliseconds since 1.1.1970. So there is a time component but it is not displayed externally.

For example the code

```
java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis())

System.out.println(utilDate);
System.out.println(sqlDate);
```

produces the output

```
Thu Jun 02 13:17:35 CEST 2016
2016-06-02
```

So be careful with sql dates and do not handle them like they would just contain a Date and no time information. For example:

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate1 = new java.sql.Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
java.sql.Date sqlDate2 = new java.sql.Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());

System.out.println(sqlDate1);
System.out.println(sqlDate2);
System.out.println(sqlDate1.equals(sqlDate2));
System.out.println(sqlDate1.toString().equals(sqlDate2.toString()));
```

prints:

```
2016-06-02
2016-06-02
false
true
```

Answer (score 2):

Java.util.Date is the generic all-purpose Date object. It stores a Date (as a long) and allows you to display it.

java.sql.Date extends java.util.Date.  Main difference to note is that java.sql.Date does not have a time component.

Answer (score 1):

## The Old

### `java.util.Date`

The [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class is part of the old date-time classes that have proven to be poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. The intent is to represent a moment (**a date and a time-of-day**) on the timeline.

The class seems to represent a moment in UTC, except that its `toString` method silently applies the JVM’s current default time zone while generating the String which creates the illusion that a java.util.Date has a time zone but actually does not. Well, actually it *does* have a time zone assigned deep in its source code used for somethings internally but not obvious and not settable nor gettable. A confusing mess.

### `java.sql.Date`

The [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) makes a bad situation worse by representing the a **date-only value** (as is meant by [“DATE” in the SQL database world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Data_types)) but did so as a hack by extending `java.util.Date`. But the you are supposed to pretend it is *not* a subclass, as directed in the class doc. Furthermore, it has time-of-day but pretends not to by adjusting to first moment of the day in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). A confusing mess.

And one more thing… the `java.sql.Date` class adds on a fractional second with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). That goes beyond the [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) resolution used by java.util.Date. Many databases support finer resolutions such as [microsecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond) or nanosecond.

So in these old date-time classes there is no way to truly represent a date-only value with no time-of-day nor time zone.

## The New

The [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework comes to the rescue. Inspired by the highly successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project. Built into Java 8 and later. [Back-ported to Java 6 & 7](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), and further [adapted to Android](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

### `Instant`

The [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds. Clear and simple.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

> instant.toString() → 2016-06-19T02:34:55.564Z

If a `java.util.Date` is needed for use with old code, you can convert. See new methods added to the old class: [java.util.Date::toInstant()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toInstant--) and [java.util.Date.from( Instant )](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from-java.time.Instant-).

### Zoned

To adjust into some locality’s [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_clock_time), apply an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) ([`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html)) to get a [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object. Even better, if you know the proper time zone name, apply a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

For example [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal) is four hours behind [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) in summer under [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time), so we see 10 PM (22:00) on the *previous date* in code below rather than 2 AM in the example above. Going back four hours crossed over midnight into the previous date. But both the `instant` object seen above and the `zdt` object seen next **both represent the same simultaneous moment** on the timeline. Same moment in history but is “tomorrow” in Paris, Kolkata, and Auckland while “yesterday” in Montréal, Mexico City, and Honolulu.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

> zdt.toString() → 2016-06-18T22:34:55.564-04:00[America/Montreal]

### `LocalDate`

For a date-only value, use the [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class. No time-of-day nor time zone is retained.

```
LocalDate localDate = zdt.toLocalDate();
```

But note that a **time zone is crucial in determining a date** as for any given moment the date can vary around the globe by time zone. Thus the discussion above about specifying a time zone. For example, see next how we get the *18th* of June rather than the *19th*.

> localDate.toString() → 2016-06-18

If this distinction between dates by time zone is significant to your business, you should be using a date-time value stored in a database column type of `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` rather than `DATE`.

Search Stack Overflow for much more information and many examples of java.time (tag: `java-time`).

### Database

So save to a database, use a [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC) [driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) complying with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) [spec](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) (see [Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/jdbc_42.html)). Call `setObject` and `getObject` on [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to directly use the java.time objects.

If your JDBC driver does not yet support such direct use of the java.time types, use the **new methods added to the old classes** to facilitate conversion. But minimize your use of the old classes; convert into java.time immediately and use only java.time objects in your business logic.

```
java.sql.Date mySqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf( localDate );
```

And the other direction.

```
LocalDate localDate = mySqlDate.toLocalDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

java.sql.Date accepts a long integer which represents the amount of milliseconds since January 1, 1970. If the given number is negative it refers time before January 1, 1970. Remember, the encapsulated value inside the object represents only date like January 1, 1970 and no time information is stored.

java.util.Date stores both date as well as time information. 
It is more commonly used than java.sql.Date.