# Java data type to hold only date

Tags: java

Which data type in Java can hold just the date and doesn't require a time component? For example, just to store `12/07/2012`. I'm working with persisting the data to/from a database that has a date-only data type, so I'm looking for the best equivalent data type in Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from the JDK: [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html):

> A thin wrapper around a millisecond value that allows JDBC to identify
>   this as an SQL DATE value. A milliseconds value represents the number
>   of milliseconds that have passed since `January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT`.
>
> To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values
>   wrapped by a `java.sql.Date` instance must be 'normalized' by setting
>   the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the
>   particular time zone with which the instance is associated.

or from [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/): [`DateMidnight`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateMidnight.html) or [`LocalDate`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) (thanks 
@cdeszaq)

> `DateMidnight` defines a date where the time component is fixed at
>   midnight. The class uses a time zone, thus midnight is local unless a
>   UTC time zone is used.
>
> It is important to emphasise that this class represents the time of
>   midnight on any given day. Note that midnight is defined as 00:00,
>   which is at the very start of a day.

Comment: +1 for the reference to JodaTime. There's also the `LocalDate` class in JodaTime that represents just the date component. It's not a perfectly clean fit, but it has worked for my needs in the past.

Comment: The midnight-related classes and methods have been deprecated and should not be used. See the `withTimeAtStartOfDay` method. Also, the makers of Joda-Time have advised us to migrate to the java.time framework.

Comment: thanks, `java.sql.Date` was exactly what I needed. I was using `java.utils.Date` and the json serializer was messing things up.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers are out-dated.

The old date-time classes are notoriously troublesome and should be avoided.

## java.time

The [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. See [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Much of the java.time functionality is [back-ported to Jave 6 & 7](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further [adapted to Android](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2012 , 12 , 7 );
```

### Textual representation

The [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toString--) method generates a String using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

> localDate.toString() → 2012-12-07

For other formats use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

### SQL

[JDBC drivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) can use the `getObject` and `setObject` methods to directly fetch/pass the java.time types such as `LocalDate` to SQL type `DATE`.

If your driver cannot do so, fall back to using the java.sql types. New methods have been added to the old classes to facilitate conversion.

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf( localDate );
```

And the other direction.

```
LocalDate localDate = sqlDate.toLocalDate();
```

## Search Stack Overflow

Search Stack Overflow for *many* more discussions and examples of using java.time. For example, [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37912195/642706) to [this similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5298450/642706).

Answer (score 2):

Date class. It holds a UNIX timestamp. In most databases, you can specify a field to hold a timestamp as well. You can use DateFormat to format the timestamp however you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 8, you can use `java.time.LocalDate`.

Answer (score 1):

Use ***[Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)*** class that is available.

Answer (score 1):

It shows how hold only date(without time)

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

Date date= new Date();

Date todayWithOutTime =formatter.parse(formatter.format(date));
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly, `java.util.Date` is something, that in SQL have name `Timestamp`. There's no pure type for Date only, `javax.sql.Date` extends `java.util.Date` and using this type for date manipulation in Java gives you no advantage.

I'm dealing with this using apache `commons-lang` class `DateUtils`:

```
Date myDate = DateUtils.truncate(timestamp, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

This will remove the time part and leave only date part.

Answer (score 1):

Use Date class. This is the better way.